# Loop through particular worksheets in Excel and insert rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to loop through particular worksheets in Excel `Tab >>>` and `<<< Tab` and insert a new row and paste special values.

The below code allows one to loop through all worksheets but I am unsure how to loop between specific worksheets - i.e. `For Each` tab between two tabs only and not including - `Tab >>>` and `<<< Tab`.

```vb
Sub WorksheetLoop2()
     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets
        ' Insert new row here and paste special values
        ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
        MsgBox Current.Name
     Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim i As Long
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab >>>").Index + 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<<< Tab").Index - 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        MsgBox .Name
        .Rows(11).Insert, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I avoid so it doesn't run in the active sheet only? 

`Sub EditSources()
Dim i As Long
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FS Ann >>>").Index + 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<<< FS Ann").Index - 1

    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Rows(11).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next
End Sub`

Comment: I inserted this line `Rows(11).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove` in the loop and it adds 4 rows in the active sheet only and not across all the sheets

Comment: Don't post code in the comments section, edit the question and add it there along with a description of the outcome.

Comment: @OuenA I have rejected [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29264709) because the `.Rows(11)`, unlinke `Rows(11)`, is already qualified.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim i As Long
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab >>>").Index + 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<<< Tab").Index - 1
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Rows(11).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next
```

Comment: Your code might fail if there are charts in the workbook. You shouldn't mix `Worksheets` and `Sheets`, because they are two different collections. Also, your code will fail if another workbook is active. You should qualify the worksheet. Do the following:  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Rows(11).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`.